# Updating features with realtime and leaflet

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I am using leaflet within bootleaf to plot weather information on a map updating every hour. I use leaflet-realtime.js to update the weather information. The weather data is stored in a Geojson file. Bootleaf has a sidebar and its own popup to display information about the clicked marker.When I use realtime to update the Geojson, the location gets updated (e.g. moving ships) but the content of the popup does not. What I would like to know is how to do this suing realtime and realtime.on

Here is part of the code that uses realtime:

```
var tangaroa_stations = L.realtime({
    url: 'http://url/tangaroa_position_test.geojson',
    crossOrigin: false,
    type: 'json'
},
{
  interval: 10 * 1000,
  pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
    return L.marker(latlng, {
      icon: L.icon({
        iconUrl: "assets/img/tangaroa.png",
        iconSize: [32, 37],
        iconAnchor: [16, 37],
        popupAnchor: [0, -25]
      }),
      title: feature.properties.NAME,
      riseOnHover: true
    });
  },
  onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
    if (feature.properties) {
      var content = layer.feature.properties.INFO;
      layer.on({
        click: function (e) {
          $("#feature-title").html(feature.properties.NAME);
          $("#feature-info").html(content);
          $("#featureModal").modal("show");
          highlight.clearLayers().addLayer(L.circleMarker([feature.geometry.coordinates[1], feature.geometry.coordinates[0]], highlightStyle));
        }
      });

        $("#feature-list tbody").append('<tr class="feature-row" id="' + L.stamp(layer) + '" lat="' + layer.getLatLng().lat + '" lng="' + layer.getLatLng().lng + '"><td style="vertical-align: middle;"><img width="16" height="18" src="assets/img/fire.png"></td><td class="feature-name">' + layer.feature.properties.NAME + '</td><td style="vertical-align: middle;"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right pull-right"></i></td></tr>'); 

      tangaroa_stationSearch.push({
        name: layer.feature.properties.NAME,
        stn_id: layer.feature.properties.STN_ID,
        source: "TangaroaStations",
        id: L.stamp(layer),
        lat: layer.feature.geometry.coordinates[1],
        lng: layer.feature.geometry.coordinates[0]
      });
    }
  }
});


tangaroa_stations.on('update', function(e) {
/*   No idea what to do here */
});
```

What I am trying to get to update are these html contents with the data from the updated Geojson:

```
$("#feature-title").html(feature.properties.NAME);
$("#feature-info").html(content);
```

The new location works on the map after an update of the Geojson, but the html content remains the same as the previous Geojson content, not the current one.

It seems that each time the append is used a new ID is created and that ID does not have any content associated with it. On the bootleaf sidebar I just get a new entry added every 10 seconds because of the update. These new entries do not have any html content associated with them, only the original first one.

Bootleaf uses list.js to create the list and it has a function called syncSidebar. I did remove the append and try only using syncSidebar but only the oringal entry in the side bar shows and it is links to the original Geojson content.

Here is a sample of the Geojson

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "id": 0, "properties": { "STN_ID": 1, "NAME": "Ship", "STATUS": 1, "INFO": "<table style='border: 1px solid #000; padding: 5px; border-collapse: collapse;'><tr><th style='border: 1px solid #000; padding: 5px;'>Validity Time</th><td style='border: 1px solid #000; padding: 5px;'>2018-03-13 18:00:00 UTC</td></tr><tr><th style='border: 1px solid #000; padding: 5px;'>Air Temperature</th><td style='border: 1px solid #000; padding: 5px;'>0.1 C</td></tr><tr><th style='border: 1px solid #000; padding: 5px;'>Wind Speed</th><td style='border: 1px solid #000; padding: 5px;'> 45.9 knots</td></tr><tr><th style='border: 1px solid #000; padding: 5px;'>Wind Direction</th><td style='border: 1px solid #000; padding: 5px;'> 163.0 (True Degrees)</td></tr><tr><th style='border: 1px solid #000; padding: 5px;'>Pressure</th><td style='border: 1px solid #000; padding: 5px;'> 964.9 hPa</td></tr></table>", "DATETIME": "2018-03-13 18:00:00", "WS": 45.9, "WD": 190.0, "AT": 0.1, "PR": 964.9}, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ somewhere_lon, somewhere_lat ] } }

]
}
```

Does anyone have any ideas?